# CAST OR CONVERT or custom?

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, sql-convert

I have the following table strand which is ordered in ascending order except for the 1st value,

```
 Strand
 3.1.1
 3.1.1.1
 3.1.1.2
 3.1.2
 3.1.2.1
 3.1.2.2
 3.10       # this should have been at the top most
 3.2.1
 3.2.1.1
 ...
 ...
 3.20      #Similarly,this should have been above 3.2.1 and below 3.1.2.2
```

The column is in varchar and i think converting the 3.10 to 3.1 and 3.20 to 3.2 will do the trick i.e converting from varchar to decimal(1,1) only for those values, but I'm not getting how to convert or cast it for particular fields inside a column...i dont want to cast the entire column..i wont get the answer then...

Answer (score 0):

You can include an `order by` length.

```
ORDER BY
LEFT(strand,1),
RIGHT(LEFT(strand,3),1),
CASE WHEN RIGHT(LEFT(strand,4),1) <> '.' and RIGHT(LEFT(strand,4),1) <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

With this, shorter strings will appear first

Comment: but i dont want all short strings to appear first..check the conditions i have mentioned in hashtags for 3.10 and 3.20

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from @t1
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN strand like '%0%' then convert(varchar,CONVERT(float,strand)) ELSE strand END
```

[image]